# Scale toilet paper cylinder witout affecting inner hole in preparation for unity

Tags: unity

I am trying to make a toilet paper like object in blender. [image]

I have cut a hole in cylinder with boolean modifier. The problem is when I scale this object in Unity the hole gets bigger as we expect. I need to set this object so that I can scale only the outside of the cylinder. Can I restrict which parts should be scaled? Even when this is possible I don't know whether Unity will do the same thing. I'm new in Blender. Thanks for help!

Comment: On a second look i'd say it can be a blender question, if edited a bit. Because unity has none such mesh editing functions as needed in this case and blender can function as a preparetion for unity. answer is coming soon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity has only simple transform tools that cant handle this case. Blender can be used to prepare the object for this.

ShapeKeys are the way to go:

1. Setup your object either totally "full" or "empty"
2. Create a basis and a key (in *Object Data* properties)
3. Select key and edit/scale your mesh with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to full/empty in *Edit Mode*.
4. Export to unity as FBX.
5. Import BlendShapes should be active by default
6. In the *Skinned Mesh Render > BlendShapes* play with your keys

Important: the collider of your base object is static, transformations with BlendShapes have no affect on the collider.

Comment: Thank you so so so much!!!! Finally I have achieved what I want. I was thinking so much how I could get this done but had no idea about these blendshapes. Thanks again! :))